# Notifications on next ssh login

Tags: ssh, cron, diff

This is a hypothetical question because I'd like to know if it's even possible before I delve in to scripting it, but is it theoretically possible to have the output of a script/process (in particular one run via `cron` for instance) spit out in to terminal on the next `ssh` login?

Some pseudocode that I hope illustrates my point:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Download latest example of a database (updated automatically and periodically)
wget -mirror "http://somedatabase/database_latest

# Run a command that generates an output for a set of files queried against the latest database)
for file in /some/dir/*;
do
    command -output $file.txt -database database_latest
done

# Now for the bit I'm more interested in.
# If the database has been updated, the 'output.txt' 
# for each file will be different.
# So, using diff...:

if [ diff $file.txt $file_old.txt == 1 ] # where file_old.txt is 
                                         # the output of the command the 
                                         # last time it ran for that file.
    then
        mv $file_old ./archive/ # Keep the old file but stash it in a separate dir
    else
        break
fi

 # Make some report file from all of the outputs
 cat *.txt > report.txt
```

So my question being, is it possible to have the script 'inform me' next time I log in to our server, if any differences were found for each file? There are a lot of files, and the 'report.txt' would become large quickly, so I only want to check it if differences are found.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a script on each login, or how to write a script looking for changes in a file? To run a script on each login, take a look at .bashrc and .bash_profile

Comment: No my plan is to have this script run weekly or fortnightly via `cron` or similar (so that it is likely that a new database has been released). To save me from trawling through the report every time it is generated (because of it's size) in the event that there are differences found, I'd like to be notified somehow, such as a message in terminal on next login - if that is possible.

Comment: it seems to me these are two different scripts. One which generates some output (to a file), and another which checks if the contents of this file is changed since the last login. Correct?

Comment: That is the gist yes - I suppose they could be run as 2 separate scripts. To my naive brain I was going to do it all in one script, and as one cron-job, but it doesn't have to be that way now you mention it. If splitting the task up allows it to be done that's fine.

Comment: The two functions are triggered differently: the download is triggered by the time (cron), the check is triggered by your login (which might be more or less often than the download). You probably want to check the differences since the last login, not between downloads.

Comment: Your pseudo-code seems like a good startingpoint, just split it at the middle. The test you are looking for is probably: if diff -q $old $new > /dev/null ; then echo files are equal ; else echo files differ ; fi

Comment: Ah, thats sounds like a good idea. So perhaps a .bashrc _profile script to manage the difference checking so that when I log in, it performs the check? Incidentally, how quick is `diff` when it comes to checking large/many files? I haven't tested it yet to know what sort of timescale I'm expecting.

Comment: Impossible to say, the speed of diff depends on too many factors. However, diff -q will quit on first difference, so if the files differ on the first line, this will be pretty quick.

Comment: Great, If you want to formalise the advice/feedback as an answer I'll accept it for the thread. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

- create three directories: `new`, `cur`, `old`
- your weekly cronjob writes data to `new`. This script should delete everything from new before writing new data. Or else you won't be able to notice that a file is missing
- `cur` contains the last version of the data that you looked at or consideret
- `old` contains the previous version of the data

Each time you log on, run:

```
#!/bin/bash

# clear the archive
rm old/*

# move all the old files to the archive
cp cur/* old

# move all the new files to the location of the old
cp new/* cur

# show which files have changed between
diff -q cur old | tee report.txt
```

The `diff`-command will print which files are new, which are missing and which are changed. Output from `diff` will also be in `report.txt`. The `cur`-directory will contain all files from the last run and you can look closer at these in an editor, or you can compare them to the previous version in `old`. Note that if a file is missing in `new`, it won't be deleted from `cur`. The next time you log on, you will lose the contents of the `old`-directory. If you want to keep a history of all previous results, this should be managed by the weekly cronjob, not the login-script (you want to store a separate version each time you generate the data, not each time you log in)