# output from diff whist in if statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement, diff

I'm using a `diff` operation to check a couple of files, but am wondering if I can simultaneiously use it to trigger an event (e.g. `echo`-ing a line to terminal etc) without having to 'manually' check for the existence of the output report.

I had thought about using the report creation as a trigger, but as far as I know the file would be created regardless, it would just be empty in the event of no differences?

Basically, is it possible to have `diff` output a file, whilst inside an `if` statement, to keep my bash profile and the script itself as tidy as possible?

(If it helps, this is a follow on question to the wonderful help I received in this question: [Notifications on next ssh login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066125/notifications-on-next-ssh-login))

e.g. something to this effect?:

```
if [ diff filex filey > report.txt == true ]
   # So the report.txt is created but the 'state' of
   # the diff query is preserved and evaluated...
     then echo "Files are different"
     else
         break
fi
```

Hope that makes sense.

This is in Ubuntu bash FYI.

Comment: I did find that link, but it didn't appear to be considering the creation of a file from the output of diff whilst also using it to evaluate the statement, they were only doing the latter (but please do correct me if I've got that wrong?)

Comment: It's close enough that I thought it worth flagging. However, I also answered it. At least one of the answers there is the same as my answer below (although I point out that redirection makes no difference to the exit status and that's all the if statement uses, in this case).

Comment: Perfect that's all I needed! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `diff` exits with a status of 0 if there is no diffs (that's shell for "true"), so you can do it like this:

```
if ! diff <file1> <file2>
then
  do the thing when there are diffs
else
  do the thing when all is same
fi
```

This should work even if you redirect the output.